# comment-ui package implementation in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, comments

I'm trying to implement comment-ui package in meteor but it's not working. The steps which I followed were

1. meteor add comment-ui
2. `<div class="comment-section">
           {{> commentsBox id=xyz}}
       </div>
       <div  id="xyz">  </div>`
   added above code to my **main.html**

Comment: I'm trying to build a comment feed using this package

Comment: ```id=xyz``` is ```xyz``` a helper that returns the document ID or is it the actual ID of the document? If it's the actual document ID, try ```id='xyz'``` ?